# Can we modify the number of tablets/shards per table after we create a universe?

Tags: yugabytedb

As described in [this](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/explore/linear-scalability/) example each tserver started with 12 tablet as we set number of shards to 4.

[image]

And when we added a new node the number of tablet per tserver became 9. it seems the total number of tablet, which is 36, will not increase.

[image]
My question is:

How many node could we add while we have 36 total tablet(in this example)?

And Is it possible to increase shards count in a running universe to be able to add more node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How many node could we add while we have 36 total tablet(in this example)?

In this example, you can expand to 12 nodes (each node would end up with 1 leader and 2 followers).

**Reasoning:** There are 36 total tablets for this table and the replication factor is 3. So there will 12 tablet leaders and 24 tablet followers. Leaders are responsible for handling writes and reads (unless you're doing follower reads, lets assume that is not the case). If you go to 12 nodes, each node would at least have one leader and be doing some work.

Ideally, you should create enough tablets upfront so that you end up with 4 tablets per node eventually.

> And Is it possible to increase shards count in a running universe to be able to add more node?

This is currently not possible, but being worked on and getting close to the finish. expected to be released in Q1 2020. If you are interested in this feature, please subscribe to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/1004) for updates.

Until that is ready, as a workaround, you can split the table into sufficient number of tablets.